# Retrieving multiple data in Firebase with Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the database
[image]

I'm trying to append isDisable to an array

What i've come so far:

```
func retrieving(){
        Database.database().reference().child("ServingHours/\(choosenDate)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            if let eachDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
                for each in eachDict{
                    print(each.value)
                }
            }
        }, withCancel: {(Err) in
        })
    }
```

with the result in console:

```
{
    isDisable = false;
    numberOfRegistration = 0;
}
{
    isDisable = false;
    numberOfRegistration = 0;
}
{
    isDisable = false;
    numberOfRegistration = 0;
}
{
    isDisable = false;
    numberOfRegistration = 0;
}
```

From this, I don't know what to do to get a specific value from `each.value`

Comment: Isn’t that another dictionary?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry but I don't really get it.

Answer (score 0):

You're retrieving your specific dates objects which have 2 items within them (isDisable and numberOfRegistration).  When you retrieve them from Firebase, you're type casting them into NSDictionary using "as?".

Your values seem to be in String format, therefore, you can retrieve them from the NSDictionary using:

```
let isDisabled = eachDict["isDisable"] as? String
let numberOfRegistration = eachDict["numberOfRegistration"] as? String
```

You can also directly set your values in Firebase to be a Bool or Int and you can typecast your retrieved objects into Bool (isDisable) and Int (numberOfRegistration).  But it looks like they are currently Strings, so your code would like this:

```
func retrieving(){
        Database.database().reference().child("ServingHours/\(choosenDate)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            if let eachDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
                    let isDisabled = eachDict["isDisable"] as? String
                    let numberOfRegistration = eachDict["numberOfRegistration"] as? String
                    print(isDisabled)
                    print(numberOfRegistration)

            }
        }, withCancel: {(Err) in
        })
    }
```

Also, if you want to retrieve a value directly, then you don't need to use an NSDictionary. You can just directly cast that value you retrieve into whatever type of object you have.  For example, say you want to retrieve your "isDisable" value directly:

```
func retrieving(){
            Database.database().reference().child("ServingHours/\(choosenDate)").child("isDisable").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
                if let isDisable = snapshot.value as? String{
                       print(isDisable) }
```

Check out the Firebase official documentation for Swift:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: it prints `nil` when I tried `let isDisabled = eachDict["isDisable"] as? String`

Comment: Did you write your isDisabled data to Firebase as a Bool or String?  Try "as? Bool" if you wrote to Firebase as a Bool.

Also, you don't need the "for each in eachDict" loop since you are trying to get specific values from the dictionary.  You only would use that if you were iterating through all of the values.

Comment: isDisable in firebase is a String.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast to a dictionary once again (and don't use NSDictionary)

```
if let eachDict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
    for each in eachDict {
        if let innerDict = each as? [String: AnyObject] {
             //innerDict now contains isDisable and numberOfRegistration
            if let isDisable = innerDict["isDisable"] as? String
                print(isDisable)
            }
            if let numberOfRegistration = innerDict["numberOfRegistration"] as? String {
                print(numberOfRegistration)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At  `if let innerDict = each as? [String: String]`, we have a warning `Cast from '(key: String, value: AnyObject)' to unrelated type '[String : String]' always fails`. And the console print nothing

Comment: @baole then try to cast to [String: AnyObject] instead